# What are the shortcut keys that uses in salesforce developer console for fast coding

Tags: developer-console

All shortcut keys that used in salesforce developer console for fast coding, Like:
Tab switching, move line up ad below, code commenting etc.

Answer (score 8):

All shortcuts are listed in a dialog popup; It appears when you press `CTRL + SHIFT + ?` or click `Help` -> `Shortcut Keys` in developer console.

Here is the screenshot on how it looks like-
[image]

Note: It is recommended to use a Salesforce IDE instead as it retains history and has lot of extra features.

---

Right now [VScode](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/extension_vscode) has best support for Salesforce development.

With latest release, it even supports normal salesforce org without use of DX: [Develop Against Any Org in Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Develop-Against-Any-Org-in-Visual-Studio-Code)